# Exclude NPM packages from update

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm using `npm` for my React Native project and I'm trying to ignore few packages during `npm update`.

For example, I want to keep my React package always on `react@16.3.1`.
But each time I run `npm update` it gets updated to `react@16.4.1`.

Any ideas how could I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It behaves depending on the [Semantic Versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning) of the NPM. Inside dependencies of your package.json file if the react version is specified as `"react": "16.3.1",` then your react version will not get updated.

Comment: In case anyone comes here when using `ncu` (i.e. "npm-check-updates"), use [the `-x` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to exclude packages from being upgraded by `ncu`. E.g. `ncu -x react`.

Answer (score 11):

In your `package.json` file use `"react": "~16.3.1"` instead of `"react": "^16.3.1"` i.e. replace caret (which means equals or higher version) with tilda.

**EDIT:** @Gabriel Carnerio's point is valid. Tilda is for when minor version changes are ok. Remove it and use `"react": "16.3.1"` if you want exact v16.3.1

Comment: It'll get minor changes, to fix the version you should put just the version.

Answer (score 9):

Just change the `package.json`.

Where is:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.1"
  }
}
```

Change to:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1"
  }
}
```